# How to estimate effort when the story involves a large number of repeat processes?

Tags: story-points, estimation

In our organization we occasionally have stories that involve a very large number of repeated process. The process itself is very simple and straightforward and usually we give 2~3 points.

When the story is all about repeating this process 50 times, do I just estimate the effort point of the whole story to be something like 100 or 150 and then break it down to smaller numbers, and complete these in a duration of several sprints?

NOTE: There isn't any way to expedite the process or create automated script to shorten the time.

Comment: What is, exactly, the question?

Answer (score 3):

A **user story** should be able to be **completed in one sprint**. So you should break it down if necessary.

Take care that you are able to divide stories in tasks that last at least a few days. Otherwise you will not be able to track progress during the dailys.
In addition reporting progress and "keep the cards moving" on the board is good for motivation.

The **estimation of the story points** should still be based on the effort (see [Aligning story points' value](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/aligning-story-points-value)). If you have a high effort to achieve a user story, it should get "a lot of" points.
Based on this information, it is the job of the product owner to prioritize the story with respect to the customer value.

Comment: Your are so right, don't know what came to my mind. I updated my answare. Nevertheless the core message remains the same